# how to use css flex box and css grid instead of float and absolute positions as described?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float, css-position, css-grid

This code below is using float to adjust image beside content.
how could i have the same result not using float or positions but only css grid or/and flex-box?(aiming to implement the picture below which red section is just one div and yellow could be an image beside the red not over-lapping it)

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

span {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos excepturi in modi nam nesciunt omnis quisquam, sed voluptates. Aspernatur at ea, explicabo facere illo iusto maiores nisi optio placeat quaerat quas quia ullam velit. Consequuntur culpa inventore saepe unde. Adipisci alias aspernatur blanditiis commodi consequuntur debitis dolorum ea eaque eos, est fugit ipsam iure, laudantium magni minima minus molestias mollitia neque officia pariatur perferendis quam quia quis reprehenderit sint tempore temporibus voluptatibus. Eos expedita nisi nobis quos reiciendis saepe tempora vero voluptas. Consequatur deleniti ea error Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex incidunt maiores molestiae nulla optio ratione rerum, sed voluptatem. Dolorum, earum, ipsa? Animi dolore doloremque eos, inventore ipsum itaque nobis nulla porro, qui rem repellendus reprehenderit saepe sapiente tenetur totam vel, velit voluptatibus. Amet ducimus earum fuga fugit labore, magnam nemo optio praesentium quidem repellendus sit veniam veritatis. Ab accusamus culpa cum cumque, dicta dolore doloremque earum esse eveniet facilis iure iusto laboriosam maxime nihil possimus provident quaerat, quam quas quia quod repellat, repellendus repudiandae rerum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ab alias asperiores consectetur consequatur debitis dolore esse est eveniet illum laboriosam libero magni, molestias mollitia nemo nulla numquam odio perspiciatis quis similique temporibus vero vitae voluptates? Aliquid aperiam aut deleniti dignissimos incidunt necessitatibus perferendis velit. Accusantium animi aperiam architecto aspernatur atque consequuntur distinctio dolor dolorem ea eius esse et harum illum impedit in incidunt ipsam ipsum iste libero magnam neque perspiciatis porro qui, reprehenderit soluta tempore veniam vitae. Cupiditate ea eligendi fugiat officiis perferendis provident repellendus sit, sunt velit voluptatem! Asperiores consequatur deserunt inventore, minus molestias neque similique velit voluptates?sapiente sit tempore tenetur ullam ut vel voluptate. Doloribus eveniet facilis ipsam tenetur voluptatem. eum ipsum maxime minus, officia omnis optio praesentium quisquam ratione, recusandae rerum sunt tempore!</span>
</div>
```

Visual example of the question

[image: Visul example of question]

Comment: *how could i have the same result not using float or positions but only css grid or/and flex-box?* --> you cannot, flexbox/CSS grid cannot (and will never) replaced float

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. I've used approximations for the size of the div's just from what I see in your problem. But the end result is the same I suppose

```css
.main{
 display:flex;
 background-color : red;
 height:100vh;
}

.main div{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p, span{
  padding: 10px;
}

.main div:nth-child(1){
  flex: 1;
  height:50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main div:nth-child(2){
  flex: 2;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <p>Section 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Section 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will helpful for you.

```css
.flex_box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex_box img {
  width: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.flex_box p {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_box">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos excepturi in modi nam nesciunt omnis quisquam, sed voluptates. Aspernatur at ea, explicabo facere illo iusto maiores nisi optio placeat quaerat quas quia ullam velit. Consequuntur culpa inventore saepe unde. Adipisci alias aspernatur blanditiis commodi consequuntur debitis dolorum ea eaque eos, est fugit ipsam iure, laudantium magni minima minus molestias mollitia neque officia pariatur perferendis quam quia quis reprehenderit sint tempore temporibus voluptatibus. Eos expedita nisi nobis quos reiciendis saepe tempora vero voluptas. Consequatur deleniti ea error Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex incidunt maiores molestiae nulla optio ratione rerum, sed voluptatem. Dolorum, earum, ipsa? Animi dolore doloremque eos, inventore ipsum itaque nobis nulla porro, qui rem repellendus reprehenderit saepe sapiente tenetur totam vel, velit voluptatibus. Amet ducimus earum fuga fugit labore, magnam nemo optio praesentium quidem repellendus sit veniam veritatis. Ab accusamus culpa cum cumque, dicta dolore doloremque earum esse eveniet facilis iure iusto laboriosam maxime nihil possimus provident quaerat, quam quas quia quod repellat, repellendus repudiandae rerum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ab alias asperiores consectetur consequatur debitis dolore esse est eveniet illum laboriosam libero magni, molestias mollitia nemo nulla numquam odio perspiciatis quis similique temporibus vero vitae voluptates? Aliquid aperiam aut deleniti dignissimos incidunt necessitatibus perferendis velit. Accusantium animi aperiam architecto aspernatur atque consequuntur distinctio dolor dolorem ea eius esse et harum illum impedit in incidunt ipsam ipsum iste libero magnam neque perspiciatis porro qui, reprehenderit soluta tempore veniam vitae. Cupiditate ea eligendi fugiat officiis perferendis provident repellendus sit, sunt velit voluptatem! Asperiores consequatur deserunt inventore, minus molestias neque similique velit voluptates? sapiente sit tempore tenetur ullam ut vel voluptate. Doloribus eveniet facilis ipsam tenetur voluptatem. eum ipsum maxime minus, officia omnis optio praesentium quisquam ratione, recusandae rerum sunt tempore!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...but i think it's different than what i intended. i was aming for the exact float picture as i mentioned which means the text of red section would be beside and under the pic as a single div not just beside it.